# Board Game Implementation in Java

Tags: java, implementation, class-diagram

First of all, I am not sure whether it is allowed to ask this kind of question. So I am trying to create a board game and I was stuck at the implementation of generating valid moves for Piece. Here is the extract of the class diagram.

[image: Class Diagram]

You can think this board game like chess, so we need to know the location of other pieces while generating valid moves. The problem is I have no idea how to check it. Is my class diagram wrong? Or should I check at the board every time I check a square? And how do I do that in Java? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you have any code in place to support your question?

Comment: A UML diagram, the world's #1 way to show you're still a student ;) As for the question - the piece should not decide what its valid moves are, it should only  be aware of where it is and how it's capable of moving, the board should manage whether or not that's allowed or not (that is, it takes a piece which returns its possible moves to it, and in turn returns the valid moves)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: you should make that an answer and the OP should accept it.

Comment: @BrianTopping I didn't think it was good enough - but since you asked I added it as an answer - thanks.

Comment: I don't have any code yet because I'm still designing class diagrams before implements it.

Comment: @jamesalone that doesn't happen in the real world either :D Design is an iterative process, even if you open a UML book like Martin Fowler's "UML distilled" it contains quotes about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The piece should not decide what its valid moves are, it should only  be aware of where it is and how it's capable of moving. It is not responsible for that sort of logic.

The board should manage whether or not that's allowed or not (that is, it takes a piece which returns its possible moves to it, and in turn returns the valid moves).

The `Piece` class exposes a `getPossibleMoves` method that returns the list of positions it can reach:

```
public List<Square> getPossibleMoves(){ // might want to differentiate types of moves
```

Then, the board class has a `getValidMoves` method that takes a piece and returns its valid moves.

```
public List<Square> getValidMoves(Piece piece) {
    return piece.getPossibleMoves().
                 stream(). // and filter by 
                 filter(move -> isOnValidBoardCoordinate(move)). // can shorten
                 filter(move -> doesNotIntersectOtherPiece(move)).
                 filter(move -> otherValidation(move)).
                 collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I have thought of that as well, the problem is, I have different types of piece, so it means I have to check the type of the piece right?

Comment: No, a piece only returns the possible moves - this should be a polymorphic method.

Comment: You mean to implement the rule of movement in the 'Piece' class? I'm seriously confused.

Comment: @jamesalone added an example